# Python and Server Load

Tags: python

Is there a way, using Python, to check the server load of a Linux machine periodically and inform me of it in some way?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Python has a function to get the system's load average as part of the os module

```
>>> import os
>>> os.getloadavg()
(1.1200000000000001, 1.0600000000000001, 0.79000000000000004)
```

From there, you can do whatever checks you need, and then email you, or similar.

Comment: Can i put the Python script into a cron job?

Comment: @Antonis `30 * * * * /usr/bin/python ~/my_script.py` or even  `30 * * * * /usr/bin/python -c "import os; os.getloadavg()"`

Answer (score 9):

[`os.getloadavg()`](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.getloadavg)