# Python - how to check system load?

Tags: python, multithreading

I am writing a script to check if the given urls are proper and resolve an IP. I'd like to fasten things up so I decided to put it into multiple threads. However, I want to make sure that the scripts does not overload the server it runs on. The question is: how can I check system load in the script? Or is there some way to determine how much threads can be run simultanously?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get current CPU and RAM usage in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/276052/how-to-get-current-cpu-and-ram-usage-in-python)

Comment: ..or duplicate of: [Python and Server Load](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4153881/python-and-server-load)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try psutil (https://github.com/giampaolo/psutil):

```
import psutil
psutil.cpu_percent()
```

psutil implements and emulates getloadavg(), also on Windows:

```
 >>> psutil.getloadavg()
 (3.14, 3.89, 4.67)
```

Comment: Able to read? """It currently supports Linux, Windows, OSX and FreeBSD, both 32-bit and 64-bit, with Python versions from 2.4 to 3.3 by using a single code base. Pypy is also known to work."""

Answer (score 23):

As suggested in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4153901/616317) maybe using:

```
>>> import os
>>> os.getloadavg()
(0.66, 0.69, 0.58)
```

It's more what you're looking for since that's the server load, not just the cpu usage.

Comment: os.getloadavg() is not for Windows.